# How to add a menu to a Xamarin.Forms ToolbarItem?

Tags: toolbar, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a way to add a menu to my ToolbarItem. Right now its just clickable text, here is an example of what I am trying to create,

[image: Menu on Toolbar]

Here is what I have so far:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding EditButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}" Clicked="EditClicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: This sample also might help you: https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleToolbarsForms

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to set the `order` of the `ToolBarItem` to `Secondary` to force the option into an overflow menu on Android:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding EditButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}" Clicked="EditClicked" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use [`Activated`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem/) instead of [`Clicked`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem/) event.

Comment: @How we can show icons and text ?  i am struggling with that

Comment: @JibinMathew have you ever found an answer for this? pleas share if you found anything

Comment: How to replicate that exact same in iOS ?