# Xamarin Forms - How do I add extra controls to the top bar in a MasterDetailPage?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, toolbar

Please see the attached image:

[Highlighted top bar in Android add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raxFO.png)

How do I add items such as the ones highlighted in the picture, on the top bar (near the hamburger menu / title), when using a MasterDetailPage with Xamarin Forms?

More precisely, I need to add these type of controls to the highlighted area in the second image:

[Highlighted Xamaring Forms top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8xlZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Toolbar.

In the tool bar you can add [ToolbarItem](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem/).

From code :

```
var contentPage = new ContentPage ();
page.ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem (....));
```

from XAML :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem .... />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530457/1155650) too.

You should be able to set the `Order` of the `ToolBarItem` to `Secondary` to force the option into an overflow menu on Android:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding EditButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}" Clicked="EditClicked" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The following forum threads should help you :

1. [Icon image on Toolbar item in xamarin Forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19225/icon-image-on-toolbar-item-in-xamarin-forms)
2. [Adding toolbar items, buttons and menus](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23714/adding-toolbar-items-buttons-and-menus)

Use the properties to get the toolbar to your liking :

- [Order](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem.Order/) - Gets or sets a value that indicates on which of on the primary, secondary, or default toolbar surfaces to display this ToolbarItem element.
- [Priority](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem.Priority/) - Gets or sets the priority of this ToolbarItem element.
- [Icon](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem.Icon/) - Gets or sets a string that identifies the image that is displayed on this ToolbarItem element.

Comment: @Rohit-  I have created ToolBarItem with a Cart Icon. Now I want to show badge (Product Count) on Cart Icon. I tried a lot but fail to modify its icon or even add anything in toolbarItem. Please help if you can in this matter.

Comment: Please open a new question on the issue with what you have tried. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rohit mentioned You can do something like this:

```
private void ShowToolbarItems()
{
ToolbarItem toolbarItem;
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    // move layout under the status bar
    this.Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

    toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem("Sync", "sync_icon.png", () =>
    {
        SyncService();
    }, 0, 0);
    ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);
}

if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{

    toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem("Sync", "sync_icon.png", () =>
    {
        SyncService();
    }, 0, 0);
    ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);

}
```

Where "sync_icon.png" is a Resource on your iOS/Android/WP projects. Hope this helps.

Here is also a great blog post for Material design in Android:

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Comment: only `this.Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);` is platform specific, you can put rest of it outside the if

Comment: Thanks to both you (Mario Galvan) and Rohit, much appreciated!